# Selecting from a specific SSAS Database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server, dmx-ssas

I'm trying to set up a prediction service for my database, I'm using OPENQUERY to ask the SSAS for predictions on my datasets. So far everything has worked fine but when I tried to scale the service I ran into some problems.

My MSSQL database server is linked to my SSAS database server using a Linked Server construction. (Linked_AS)

I've run into the problem that I cannot seem to specify a specific SSAS database that I would like to select my mining structure from. The DMX syntax simply doesn't seem to support it.

For reference here is the select query.

```
SELECT * from OPENQUERY(Linked_AS, 'SELECT  flattened top 1 timeindex FROM fillpercentageDaily.CASES
order by timeindex desc'));
```

This query runs fine but seems highly ambiguous as there is no way for me to determine which database it is selecting from.

Workaround I can think of:

- Making sure that all of my mining structure names are unique across all databases.

However this does not seem practical. Is there anyone that has some insights?

Comment: This is known.   You have to create a separate linked server for every SSAS database.   You know which database you are selecting from because you know which Linked Server you are querying.